# Angular Radio button Issue

Tags: angular, radio-button

Whenever I click on the radio button "second" I have to click it twice for that to be selected.

does ngModel not accept! (negation)?

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="custom-radio black">first
    <input type="radio" name="name" required [value]=false [(ngModel)]="!selectedValue" class="black" checked="true">
    <span class="checkdot"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="custom-radio black">second
    <input type="radio" name="name" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" required [value]=true checked="true" class="black">
    <span class="checkdot"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Try removing `checked="true"` and also removing the negation in `[(ngModel)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"` same for both,

as its radio button so it can have only one value at a time, there is no need of `checked="true"` also, it will be marked once `[(ngModel)]` and `[value]` has same value

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-radio-issue)**

Comment: Of course, getting rid of checked wouldn't hurt either.